# Redux save filters in state

Tags: javascript, redux

I have a page with multiple select filters, for example:

```
 const filtersOne = [{id: 1, title: "Filter one"}, {id: 2, title: "Filter two", active: true}]
 const filtersTwo = [{id: 1, title: "Filter 1"}, {id: 2, title: "Filter 2", active: true}]
```

From this data, I will render select boxes.

My question is what the best way to save this data in my store?

```
const state = {

  page: {
    filters: {
      filtersOne: [{id: 1, title: "Filter one"}, {id: 2, title: "Filter two", active: true}],
      filtersTwo: [{id: 1, title: "Filter 1"}, {id: 2, title: "Filter 2", active: true}] 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer child objects like you have done, but the documentation for redux says avoid nesting....

Comment: So how you do it without nesting?

Comment: The other option you have, is no nesting, but descriptive names, `filtersForUsers`

Comment: What do you mean how do you do it, implementation of it, or reading of the state?

Comment: The implementation without nesting

Comment: page: {  ...descriptive names }?

Comment: Can we just confirm, have you implemented the redux pattern, do you have a `store.js` holding the store implementation?

Comment: Yes I have the store.

Comment: This [documentation](http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Store.html) should tell you exactly how to do it.

Comment: My question was if you would write the descriptive names inside the page object?

Comment: nope, they would be the highest level.